# Connecting from WebLogic 11g to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am unable to set up a WebLogic 11g data source to our SQL Server database.  Can you please help diagnose the error

> weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection.
>   The DBMS driver exception was: [FMWGEN][SQLServer JDBC
>   Driver][SQLServer]Login failed for user 'carynt\posapp'

The value `carynt\posapp` is the value I specify for the user.  I have attempted various different "AuthenticationMethod" settings as prescribed [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/jdbc_drivers/mssqlserver.html#wp1096945).

My unit tests (from within the Eclipse IDE) run successfully.  However those use [integratedSecurity settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#sectionToggle3).  Is it possible to somehow use similar settings for the WebLogic datasource?

Comment: Can you please provide the entire jdbc connection pool string ?

Comment: @yabmob Thanks for offering to help.  However I have found a solution. See my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

We noticed an error in the WebLogic console logs about an unrelated class not being found.  Our WebLogic administrator correctly diagnosed it as owing to the tweaked `java.library.path` (as suggested for using [integratedSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx#sectionToggle3)).

We could not determine *which* of the myriad WebLogic's startup scripts was initializing the `java.library.path` value.  Obviously my setting of this variable was clobbering the original value.  By *undoing* my changes we noticed that the *default* `java.library.path` was the same as the Windows PATH system variable value.  Therefore we

1. Customized the `java.library.path` by tweaking the Windows PATH value in the `startWebLogic.cmd` file
2. Removed userid and password settings in the WebLogic data source definition
3. Added the `integratedSecurity=true` setting in the data source definition.
4. Restarted the server

Paydirt!